# Add single quotes to dict string python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Below is a dict string I have:

```
s= "{0: {name: [(.1, 0), (.2, 0), (.3, 0)], address: [(get--some\data, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]}}"
```

I tried converting the above dict string to dict type by using ast, eval, and json.loads(). Due to the dict's lack of quotes, there are some issues with that.

Would someone be able to help me add single quotes to all of the keys and values as follows:

```
s= "{'0': {'name': [('.1', '0'), ('.2', '0'), ('.3', '0')], 'address': [('get --some\data', '0'), ('2', '0'), ('3', '0')]}}"
```

I tried adding quotes using regex, but this string won't have static values, like a list of tuple values can vary in size between requests.

Here is the code I tried:

```
a = re.sub(r'((\w+)|(\w+\s*?\w+)):', r"'\1':", s)
```

above regex is helping me add quotes to keys. i would need help on adding quotes to values as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this, it could satisfy most of your cases:

- regex

```
(?!\s)([^][{}():,]+?)(?=\s*[,\):\]}])
```

- substitution

```
'\1'
```

- Python code

```py
a = re.sub(r'(?!\s)([^][{}():,]+?)(?=\s*[,\):\]}])', r"'\1'", s)
```

You can check the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/vnbphk/1)

Comment: Unfortunately, now i'm getting input like below,

`s= "{'0': {'name (64-bit)': [('.1', '0'), ('.2', '0'), ('.3', '0')], 'address (64-bit)': [('get --some\data', '0'), ('2', '0'), ('3', '0')]}}"
`
For this input regex is failing to put single quotes in correct place. Please check below link for the results and kindly help in this.
https://regex101.com/r/vnbphk/1 @HaoWu